# mySQL query size

Tags: mysql

I used to use a query in mySQL that tells me how big my query is.
However, I don't remember that query and can't seem to find it now.
Does anyone know that syntax on top of their head?

Basically it allows me to know how much in size I saved from using a 11 bit integer vs 2 bit integer etc.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: No such thing as an 11 bit or 2 bit integer. You can have a tinyint unsigned (1 byte = 8 bits), smallint unsigned (2 bytes = 16 bits), mediumint unsigned (3 bytes = 24 bits), int unsigned (4 bytes = 32 bits) and a bigint unsigned (8 bytes = 64 bits) integer datatypes

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "query size"?

Comment: @f00 - My guess is that OP meant to refer to field size, not bits.

Comment: you mean the optional display width specifier used with zerofill ?

Comment: The number often used for creating an int column, `int(11)`, refers to the column width, not the size of the data structure. Additionally, this size will only provide a noticeable effect if you use `ZEROFILL` as it merely indicates the "display" width of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an overview, also with all data types: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'MY_TABLE'` to return a bunch of information about the table. The `Data_length` column will contain the size of the data file used for that table. There is also an "average row length", `Avg_row_length`, that might be useful.

See here for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html.

As mentioned in my comment above though, the number after an int declaration, `int(11)`, does not affect the size of the data structure that holds the integer. It only affects the display width of the column. Furthermore, you will only see its effect if you are using `ZEROFILL`.